# How to open a new tab in the current window of chrome browser using robot framework with eclipse

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, selenium, robotframework

Working on automation project.

**Task**

Sign upto Saleshandy.

**My decided action**

- Open a chrome browser.
- Enter https://my.saleshandy.com/signup in url and search
- Now enter the email id and click on next button.
- Enter the First Name, Last Name, select India from the dropdown and then enter the phone number, password.
- Click on "Submit" button.
  -Now the site is asking for OTP to verify the email.

For that i want to open a new tab in the current window and login to gmail and also want to open the received mail of otp.

Then copy that OTP and again switch to the first tab and paste that otp.

**My Method**

Chromedriver
Using Robot Framework with Eclipse editor.
Using Selenium Library

**My Code**

`

```
*** Settings ***

Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

FirstSeleniumTest

   Open Browser    https://my.saleshandy.com/signup    chrome

   Maximize Browser Window
    
   Input Text    name=email    keval+9999@saleshandy.com

   Click Button    //button[@type='submit']
   
   Wait Until Page Contains Element //*@id="root"]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/input    10s
   
   Input Text    //input[@name='firstName']    Keval

   Input Text    //input[@name='lastName']    Test
   
   Click Element    //*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div

   Click Element    //*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[85]/span[1]    

   Input Text    //*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/input    8401608858

   Input Password    //*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/form/div[3]/div/div[1]/span/input    Tommy@8523

   Sleep    5s

   Click Button    //*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/form/button

   Sleep    5s

   Press Keys      None      CTRL+T
```

`

**My Problem**

```
 Below code is not working

 Press Keys      None      CTRL+T
```

What should I do to open a new(second) tab with the current browser chrome first tab.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work same as Ctrl+T in Chrome:

```js
window.open('https://www.google.com');
```

Comment: Can you please suggest the library through which I can open new tab in current window